# How to Refresh Jquery Mobile Listview after Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working in Jquery Mobile and I'm having problems refreshing the listview after Ajax content has been pulled into a div.

Specifically, the Ajax content is being pulled into a listview which resides within a collapsible content block.

**Here is my html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<title>Edit Kits</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Auer.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc2/jquery.mobile-1.0rc2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="editkits" class="type-interior">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Edit Kits</h1>
<a href="SPI_SearchLink" data-icon="home" class="ui-btn-left">Home</a>
<a data-rel="back" data-icon="back" class="ui-btn-right">Back</a>
<div class="header-sub">
<div class="ui-bar center-text"><img src="images/logo.png" id="logo" alt="spi_Cname"/></div>
</div>
<div data-role="navbar" class="navbar">
<ul>
<li><a href="SPI_TOCLink" data-theme="c">TOC</a></li>

<!-- SPI_HTML_ShowSearchMenu -->
<li><a href="SPI_SearchLink" data-theme="c">Search</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_ShowSearchMenu -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowKits -->
<li><a href="SPI_KitsLink" class="ui-btn-active" data-theme="c">Kits</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowKits -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowSales -->
<li><a href="SPI_SalesLink" data-theme="c">SPI_SalesMenuText</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowSales -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
<li><a href="SPI_ShopingCartLink" data-theme="c">Cart</a></li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_AllowOrderPlacement -->
</ul>
</div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">

<!-- SPI_No_Kit_Message -->
<div class="ui-grid-a">
<div class="ui-bar ui-bar-e center-text">
<br>
<h2>You have no saved Kits.</h2>
<p>To create a kit, add products to your shopping
cart and click "save as kit" on the menu at the bottom of your display.</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- SPI_No_Kit_Message -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_HdrOnlyKit -->
<div data-role="collapsible" class="kit" id="SPI_KitId" data-collapsed="true" data-content-theme="d">
<h3>SPI_KitName SPI_KitNote</h3>
<div class="kitid"></div>
</div>
<!-- SPI_HTML_HdrOnlyKit -->

<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit -->
<h3><a href="WebCatPageServer.exe?AJAX&Action=Close_Kit&KitID=SPI_KitId">SPI_KitName SPI_KitNote</a></h3>
<form name="SPI_KitFormName" method="post" action="WebCatPageServer.exe">
<input name="Action" type="hidden" value="Not_Set" />
<input name="IsAjax" type="hidden" value="Yes" />
<input name="KitId" type="hidden" value="SPI_KitId" />
<input name="SearchTerm" type="hidden" value="Not_Set" />
<ul data-role="listview" id="list" data-inset="true" data-split-icon="delete" data-split-theme="d">
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product1 -->
<li><a href="javascript:document.ShoppingCart.Action.value='ItemLookup';document.ShoppingCart.SearchTerm.value='SPI_CartLookupPartNum';document.ShoppingCart.submit();">
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<h2>SPI_KitProdPartNum</h2>
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<p class="description">SPI_KitProdDesc</p>
<p><input type="text"  name="SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName" onBlur="clickrecall(this,'0')" tabindex="SPI_KitOrdQtyTabIndex" value="SPI_KitProdQty"  onfocus="document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.select()"/></p>
<p>Unit Price: SPI_KitProdPrice</p>
<p>Ext. Price: <span class="price">SPI_KitProdExtPrice</span></p>
</a>
<a href="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.value='DEL';document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();">Delete</a> 
</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product1 -->
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product2 -->
<li><a href="javascript:document.ShoppingCart.Action.value='ItemLookup';document.ShoppingCart.SearchTerm.value='SPI_CartLookupPartNum';document.ShoppingCart.submit();">
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<h2>SPI_KitProdPartNum</h2>
<!-- SPI_KitProdItemNum -->
<p class="description">SPI_KitProdDesc</p>
<p><input type="text"  name="SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName" onBlur="clickrecall(this,'0')" tabindex="SPI_KitOrdQtyTabIndex" value="SPI_KitProdQty"  onfocus="document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.select()"/></p>
<p>Unit Price: SPI_KitProdPrice</p>
<p>Ext. Price: <span class="price">SPI_KitProdExtPrice</span></p>
</a>
<a href="javascript:document.SPI_KitFormName.SPI_KitOrdQtyFieldName.value='DEL';document.SPI_KitFormName.Action.value='Recalc_Kit';document.SPI_KitFormName.submit();">Delete</a> 
</li>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit_Product2 -->
</ul>
</form>
<!-- SPI_HTML_Kit -->

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" id="footer" data-position="fixed">
<h4>&copy; Auer Steel 2011</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->


</div><!-- /page -->
</body>
</html>
```

**Here's my ajax call:**

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
cache: false
});
var ajax_load = "<img src='images/load.gif' alt='loading...' />";
$(".kit").click(function(){
var kitid = this.id;
var loadUrl = "http://68.188.40.182/WebCat/WebCatPageServer.exe?AJAX&Action=Open_Kit&KitID=" +kitid;
$(".kitid").html(ajax_load).load(loadUrl); 
});
```

**I did try** several variations of: $("#list").listview("refresh"); to no avail.

I read somewhere that perhaps using loadUrl is the issue. Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Ok, using Avisek's code as a starting point, I was able to come up with this. This works well, except it only refreshes the first listview within the first collapsible content box. Subsequent listviews in subsequent content boxes do not refresh. Any ideas? Thanks!

I used Avisek's starting point and eventually got to this solution that seems to work:

**UPDATE II**
Ok, I seem to have solved this. I added the following code after the refresh code to in effect destroy the page after the ajax function was called on each collapsible element and subsequently each listview that was created:

```
jQuery('#editkits').page("destroy").page();
```

You can see the complete code below:

```
 $(".kit").click(function(){
    $(".kitid").empty().html('<img src="images/load.gif" />');
    var kitid = this.id;
    var url = 'http://68.188.40.182/WebCat/WebCatPageServer.exe?AJAX&Action=Open_Kit&KitID=' +kitid;
    $.ajax({
         url : url,
         dataType: "html",
         cache: false,
         success : ajaxCallDone,
         complete: function() {
          },
          error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("Error type :" + errorThrown+ " Error message :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseXML+ " textStatus: "+textStatus);
          }
        });
    function ajaxCallDone(data)
    {
      $(".kitid").html(data);
      try {
        $('#list').listview('refresh');
    } catch(e) {
         $('#list').listview();
    }
  jQuery('#editkits').page("destroy").page();
    }
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of jquery load; try ajax

and on success- populate html & on complete- do a refresh

for e.g-

```
var url = 'your_url';
var dataString = "Action=Open_Kit&KitID=" +kitid;

$.ajax({
        url : url,
        data: dataString,
        success : ajaxCallDone,
        complete: function() {
                 $("#list").listview("refresh");
        }
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Error type :" + errorThrown+ " Error message :" + XMLHttpRequest.responseXML+ " textStatus: "+textStatus);
        }
    });



function ajaxCallDone(data)
{
  //populate the html
  $(".kitid").html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.listview("refresh")` did not work for me.  It created a basic list, without styling.

This is what worked for me:

```
function updateData()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Html.Raw(ajaxUrl)',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); },
        complete: function ()
        {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
            $("ul:jqmData(role='listview')").listview();
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            $('#myDiv').html(data);
            $('#myDiv').trigger("create"); // *** THIS IS THE KEY ***
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It worked for me too. The key factor is `"ul:jqmData(role='listview')"`.

Comment: The key is really the event trigger on the div. thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In the hopes this will help someone else in the future, here's what was happening in my situation.  I was using a (somewhat) generic id for the div (#pageContent) and referencing it across several places in the app.  Once I removed that duplicate id, things started working as designed.

Thanks to everyone above for the tips and tricks! (I tried them all) :)