# jQuery Mobile - button to change list sort order?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile. How can I create a button which changes the sort order of a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your data in a separate structure which you sort, e.g.

```
var mylist = new Array ();
mylist[0] = "entry A";
mylist[1] = "entry B";
....
```

From this, you can then dynamically populate your `listview`.

In the Button's onclick event, you'll have to do the following:

- Resort your data struct (`mylist`)
- clear the listview used to display the data
- Repopulate the listview from your updated data structure.

For more details on how to clear and repopulate list, see e.g. [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091288/how-to-refresh-jquery-mobile-listview-after-ajax-call).